# Using ARRAYFORMULA and QUERY to total numbers related to Sheet A to Sheet B

Tags: google-sheets

I'm currently trying to create a formula that I can use for my Google Sheets Project. I Have two sheets (Sheet A, and Sheet B) Details on each sheet are the following:

**Sheet A**

```
A         |       B
Users       Total Number Count
User 1           2
User 2
User 3
```

**Sheet B**

```
A         |       B
Users       Total Number Count
User 1           2
User 2           4
User 3           1
User 3           2
User 3           4
User 3           1
```

I want to Tally the numbers on total number count from **Sheet B** and display them on the corresponding users on **Sheet A**

I am working with the following formula on **Sheet A — Column B**:

`QUERY(Payments, "SELECT sum(B) WHERE A ='" & A2 & "' label sum(B) 'Total Number Count'" ,)`

At the moment, it only displays a single value, I would like it to repeat for every row by using ***ARRAYFORMULA***, but have read that they do not work together. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this. Here, I will share a simple approach and will assume that your sheet names are `Sheet A` and `Sheet B` per your post. You will need to replace those with your actual sheet names if they differ.

Clear `'Sheet A'!B:B` entirely (including the header). Then place the following formula in `'Sheet A'!B1`.

`=ArrayFormula({"Total Count";IF(A2:A="",,SUMIF('Sheet B'!A:A,A2:A,'Sheet B'!B:B))})`

This formula will return the B1 header and all column results. You can change the header text within the formula itself. (You can't type directly into any cell of Col B with this formula in place, because it "owns" the entire column, as it should.)

Comment: Erik, thank you! It worked, had to adjust the actual sheets as you said. Initially it wasn't working, turns out the error was found on the ranges that I set on the named range. It's working now. Thank you

Comment: I'm glad you were able to adapt the solution to your real-world need with success.